# Parsing and evaluating arbitrary source code in Python

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
a = 1
some rubbish
b = 2
some other rubbish
c = a + b
```

And I would like to know the value of `c`.

My idea is to evaluate the file line by line since the syntax contains only simple arithmetic operation. The problem is, however, that the file also contains lines that are not valid python expression, these I would like to simply skip.

I am not afraid the file contains any malicious code, but I would prefer if the evaluation happens in some kind of 'safe environment' (different namespace?) to not interfere with the rest of the (main) code.

Comment: You should probably provide an explicit example of what "some rubbish" is, it's difficult to remove "rubbish" when you're not sure what you're looking for ;)

Comment: So you want to copy all valid python in another file and ignore all "rubbish" parts?

Comment: You could look at what [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) does.

Comment: @Bokix it also seems like they want a valid way of extracting `c` - yes you can just access `c`, but for a general variable that might be more complicated.

Comment: @mozway: Rubbish is any expression raising SyntaxError exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check each individual line and remove all those that are invalid python, you can use [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse). Drop the lines that trigger a `SyntaxError`:

```
text = '''a = 1
some rubbish
b = 2
some other rubbish
c = a + b
'''

from ast import parse

for line in text.splitlines():
    try:
        parse(line)
        print(line)
    except SyntaxError:
        pass
```

Output:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b
```

*NB. using a simple `print` for the demo but you can instead write the lines into a file:*

```
from ast import parse

with open('test.py') as f, open('out.py', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f:
        try:
            parse(line)
            f_out.write(line)
        except SyntaxError:
            pass
```

Comment: That is great. By calling ```exec(line, {}, loc_dct)```, where ```loc_dct``` is just an empty dictionary, I can access the the ```c``` variable as ```loc_dct['c']```.